# Any examples on implementing OBEX in Android app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, obex

I need to realize an Android app that permits to make file transfers and browsing the remote device file system via Bluetooth.
I think i have to implement OBEX and OPP but i have not found so many resources on the net.
Can anyone help me in finding useful material?
Thanks in advance

Comment: see also [this SO post][1] with the same aim and sample code included.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662682/implementing-obex-push-server-on-android-2-3

Comment: Copy javax.obex.* to your project..

Answer (score 1):

You can find the specifications for OPP and OBEX at the [Bluetooth.org Adopted Documents page](https://www.bluetooth.org/Technical/Specifications/adopted.htm), Note that the documents describing OBEX are labeled IrDA for "IrDA Interoperability"
.