# Android: how can i browse remote device file system via bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, obex

I need to build an Android app that puts/gets files from a remote device via Bluetooth; the app must also browse the remote filesystem.
I've read something about OBEX but have really not found any example for Android, except some great apps on the market as Bluetooth File Transfer.
How can it be implemented in an app?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBject_EXchange

Comment: thanks but i'm looking for something specific to Android

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can OBEX and OPP be implemented in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158493/how-can-obex-and-opp-be-implemented-in-android)

Comment: Already found that link, the problem is that there is no solution

Comment: What if you make an app which acts a gateway, However in this case you can let user choose which file they want to share around them, And other bluetooth android device must have that app to explore other device's shared folders. I hope you got what I mean

Answer (score 7):

Since there is no standard method/implementation of OBEX OPP/FTP that is exposed to developers on Android, you will have to roll you own over the [Bluetooth API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html) which is powerful enough implement just about any protocol you want as it mirrors TCP sockets.

The first thing you will have to do is get access to the filesystem. Assuming the SD Card, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) is a guide otherwise you would need root access. Then you want to get a Bluetooth connection working between two devices (boilerplate code). Lastly you should Google up the protocol specification for OBEX OPP/FTP and implement it which is probably going to take the most time.

I'm pretty sure that's how the other apps on the marketplace do it as they require the app on both devices in order to send/receive files and browse the filesystem. I can't go in depth on the OBEX protocol itself as I'm not familiar with it but I can elaborate on everything before that if needed. However a google search turned up [this](http://gitorious.org/android-obex/pages/Home) which may be useful while implementing.

Not sure if this will help but I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921384/how-to-send-file-using-bluetooth-on-android-programatically) to have worked for a lot of people to send files.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the built-in Android API. There are intents you can call to share files over Bluetooth - but compatibility between models varies. However, there are some methods if you would like to write an app for rooted phones. If this is the case, please note it.

Comment: My app should run in not-rooted devices. As it happens for the Bluetooth File Transfer where the user Can browse remote device file system. Thanks