# Implementing OBEX PUSH Server on Android 2.3

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to setup an in-app OBEX server on an Android 2.3 device. Using the Bluetooth Chat Sample code I was able to setup an OBEX server. However, the server needs to use a custom UUID so the service is not registered as an 'OBEX Server'

```
# sdptool browse local
...(snip)...
Service Name: OBEX Object Push
Service RecHandle: 0x10000
Service Class ID List:
  UUID 128: ab123abc-1a2b-3c4d-5d7f-1234567890ab
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 18
```

So, when I receive data, it looks like I am receiving a raw OBEX connection request:

```
80 00 07 10 00 04 00 00 00 00 ...(snip)... 00 00 00 (1kb file)
```

Is there an OBEX implementation that I can use or do I have to implement the protocol myself?

I don't want to use the inbuilt OBEX server - this has to be in app. I have tried BlueCove but I abandoned it when I had issues registering a service.

Yes, I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158493/any-examples-on-implementing-obex-in-android-app) post and read the [link](https://www.bluetooth.org/Technical/Specifications/adopted.htm) in it, but by golly, there must be an easier way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up implementing the protocol myself. It wasn't as hairy as I imagined. Since I was expecting only a specific client to connect and I knew that the client would only be pushing one file I was able to partially implement only the sections of the protocol that I needed.

Some documentation that helped with understanding the OBEX protocol were Obex13.pdf at: http://gitorious.org/gammu/gsm-docs/trees/e5161a75fb1e1c1608959b27ae3c3940bcf0911b/standards/obex

A quick snippet of how I parsed the sockets input stream:
(Note OBEXUtils and OBEXConstants are my classes.)

```
try
{
    //Read all bytes passed in
    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

    //Ensure we have the entire packet before we proceed
    // Packet length is in the 1st and 2nd byte
    expectedLength = OBEXUtils.bytesToShort(buffer[OBEXConstant.LENGTH_IDENTIFIER],
        buffer[OBEXConstant.LENGTH_IDENTIFIER + 1]);

    packetLength = bytes;

    //Keep reading until we get what we expect.
    while (packetLength < expectedLength)
    {
        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, packetLength, maxPacketSize);
        packetLength += bytes;
    }

    //Switch on Packet Header
    switch (buffer[OBEXConstant.HEADER_IDENTIFIER])
    {
        case OBEXConstant.CONNECT:
            //Parse the packet and return an acknowledgement packet
            write(OBEXConnect.parsePacket(buffer));
            break;

        case OBEXConstant.PUT:
        case OBEXConstant.PUT_FINAL:
            //Parse the PUT packet and return an acknowledgement packet
            //For Parsing PUT packets I referred to the android and bluecove implementations
            write(putPacket.appendPacket(buffer, packetLength));
            break;

        case OBEXConstant.DISCONNECT:
            //Parse the packet and return an acknowledgement packet
            write(OBEXDisconnect.parsePacket(buffer));
            break;

        case OBEXConstant.GET:
        case OBEXConstant.GET_FINAL:
        case OBEXConstant.SETPATH:
        case OBEXConstant.SETPATH_FINAL:
        case OBEXConstant.SESSION:
            //Did not implement these
            break;

        case OBEXConstant.ABORT:
            Log.w(Constant.TAG, TAG + "ABORT Request Received");
            isDisconnected = true;
            break;

        default:

            break;
    }
}
catch (final IOException e)
{
    ...(snip)...
}
```

Snip of OBEXConstant:

```
public static final byte FINAL_BIT = (byte) 0x80;

public static final byte CONNECT = 0x00 | FINAL_BIT; //*high bit always set Connect choose your partner, negotiate capabilities
public static final byte DISCONNECT = 0x01 | FINAL_BIT; //*high bit always set Disconnect signal the end of the session
public static final byte PUT = 0x02; //(0x82) Put send an object
public static final byte PUT_FINAL = PUT | FINAL_BIT;
public static final byte GET = 0x03; //(0x83) Get get an object
public static final byte GET_FINAL = GET | FINAL_BIT; //(0x83) Get get an object
public static final byte SETPATH = 0x05;
public static final byte SETPATH_FINAL = SETPATH | FINAL_BIT;
public static final byte SESSION = 0x07;
public static final byte ABORT = (byte) 0xFF;

public static final byte OBEX_RESPONSE_CONTINUE = (byte) 0x90;
public static final byte OBEX_RESPONSE_SUCCESS = (byte) 0xA0;
```

Comment: Could you provide the whole solution you made, on googlecode or github? I need to transmit som data from a bluetooth device over to my android phone, acting as a server. But I can't find any solutions for this..Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Unfortunately the source is now protected by client copyright. The android SDK bluetooth chat example is a good starting point. You can then use the code posted above to start implementing the OBEX protocol.

Comment: As I understand you are just using the android bluetooth library to connect with the device and OBEX OPP just for receiving files from this device? If I may ask, what kind of device was this? Thanks.

Comment: It's a handheld bluetooth scanner.

Comment: Are you using the UUID of Obex Object Push to listen for incomming connections? The UUID is: 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB. And used like this:  tmp = adapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(device.getName(), UUID.fromString(00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB));

Comment: No, I was using the UUID of the specific device I was trying to communicate with.  tmp = _device.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(Constant.OBEX_SERVER_NAME, Constant.OBEX_SERVER_UUID);

Comment: The link Obex13.pdf is no longer valid. Looks like it was moved to https://github.com/gammu/gsm-docs/blob/master/standards/obex/OBEX13.pdf

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps: [com.android.bluetooth.pbap.BluetoothPbapObexServer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3_r1/com/android/bluetooth/pbap/BluetoothPbapObexServer.java#BluetoothPbapObexServer)